# Master Slider text not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, masterslider

I have tried everything i can think of to get this working.

The text on the slider on my homepage is all over the place on mobile. I thought it might have been a responsive text issue? Can someone have a look help me understand what is going on here?

healthgasm.com

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. If you need help, make your question helpful to others first. It's also a good idea to create a [mcve] of the problem and to outline what *"i tried everything I can think of"* means in current context.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have top: 280px, try put it in -20px.

Here I'm going to put the class and media query code I've found in your site with the fix.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px)
.slider .ms-slide-info {
    left: 0 !important;
    top: -20px !important;
    transform: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: hey mate, thanks for your help with this but i am getting an error message when i plug it into the additional CSS area at this line:                                                               
.slider .ms-slide-info {
   any suggestions?

Comment: also you can rewrite the class and the media query and delete the !important in the top property of the code I putted above